# Nx Angular Workspace => changes to .eslintrc.json => rules are not seen in vscode

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Im trying to disable a rule. So i added the following rules to my `.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": ["../../.eslintrc.json"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "rules": {
    "no-empty-function":"off",
    "no-empty-lifecycle-method":"off"
  },
  "overrides": [...]
}
```

but the errors i was trying to silence in vscode are still showing. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: this one work for me, check it out
[How do I override an eslint rule in my nx workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069447)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your environment but it boils down to

1. initialising a new npm project `npm init`
2. installing eslint `npm install --save-dev eslint`
3. initialising eslint

Knowing what framework you're using would help, chances are you're using one so I'd recommend checking for a config guide for react/vue/node and so on.

Comment: This is an angular project using an nx workspace. eslint is working. I just cant customize error // warning // off for any of the rules.