# Angular Eslint config is not extending Project Eslint config

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

I have an angular 12.x project and it uses eslint, this is the current root configuration file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.base.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-import",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template",
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ],
  "extends": ["prettier", "eslint:recommended"],
  "rules":{... lots of rules}
}
```

One of the rules I need to work is the [member-ordering as described on their docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.28.5/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/member-ordering.md#default-configuration).

I have a libs (created using NX) that are re-usable components, let me use MyComponent for this example. That component has its own eslintrc which extends the root one, below its contents:

```
{
  "extends": ["../../../.eslintrc.json"], //path to the root eslintrc
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "suppressed",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "suppressed",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.html"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/angular-template"],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is `MyComponent` that uses uses the above eslintrc:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  @Dispatch()
  clearState() {
    return new ViewActions.ClearState();
  }

  private functio() {
    return null;
  }

  static handle() {}

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.clearState();
  }
}
```

Based on the default config of the rule as per the doc I linked, the code above should have errors starting on the `@Dispatch()` all the way to the `destroy()` due to violation of the rule.

But the output is different from the expected:
[image: component screenshot]

Now, if I add the rule config as per the docs, into my component eslintrc.json, it will work as expected which is: Method `clearState` will have the error, as it is annotated and it is expected to come before a non-annotated method, in this `ngOnInit` and errors for the private one as well.

The actual problem is that the very first line on my component eslintrc.json has `extends` targeting the root eslintrc, and I wanted to have all my rules overridden on that file. If I change the member-ordering to the root eslintrc, the rule stops working and it is reverted to that error of the image added.

Also, when running  `npx eslint --print-config .\my-component.ts` from my component directory, I get following config for member-ordering being applied:

```
"@typescript-eslint/member-ordering": [
      "error",
      {
        "default": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

I really don't know where that is coming from.

Does anyone know why my component eslint is not extending the rules from the root eslintrc?

===== Update ==========

Eslint related dependencies on package.json

```
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.3.0",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "12.9.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.28.5",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "4.12.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.28.5",
"eslint": "7.32.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.10.3",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.24.0",
"@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.3.1",
```

Comment: May be this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069447/1398461) helps. I think you should in general tend to use "root": true (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9103#issue-630135605)  in the projects.

Comment: You are correct @kuldeep. The root option might not work for some projects if you have options set to specific libraries, but that is not my case. I found some other issues being raised due to NX which I am trying to fix, but not directly related to this. Thank for pointing it out.

Comment: You may post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as it.

Comment: sure, i hope it helped you :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069447/1398461) helps. I think you should in general tend to use ["root": true](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9103#issue-630135605) in the projects.